# Redirect all requests to index.php in a folder if exists .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following project structure:

```
site
  |---admin
  |     |---index.php   (echo 'admin. request uri: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];)
  |     |---...
  |
  |---category
  |     |---index.php   (echo 'category. request uri: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];)
  |     |---...
  |
  |---...
  |
  |---index.php         (echo 'main. request uri: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];)
  |---.htaccess
```

I want to redirect all requests to index.php file in the folder, which is specified in the url (if index.php in the folder exists), otherwise redirect to root index.php file. For example:

> If url is **www.somedomain/admin/asdf**, it should be redirected to
>   **admin/index.php** file.
>
> If url is **www.somedomain/asdf**, it should be redirected to main
>   **index.php**.

In order to redirect all requests to index.php I added the following rules to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]
```

Now if I enter **www.somedomain/asdf** redirect is successful, the result is:

> main. request uri: /asdf

But if I enter **www.somedomain/admin/asdf** redirect is wrong (to the main **index.php**, but should be to the **admin/index.php**), the result is:

> main. request uri: /admn/asdf

Please help me to write correct rules in the .htaccess file for this case. The output should be the following:

> admin. request uri: /admn/asdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)[^/]+/?$ $1index.php [L]
```